# How do I cancel pending WordPress multi-site installation?

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite, cancellation

I'm trying to create a network of WordPress sites but missed selecting my target domain. Now installation wants to proceed on my default domain. I can't seem to return back to the "Create a Network of WordPress Sites - Network Details" screen. It's stuck on "Create a Network of WordPress Sites - Enabling the Network" screen.

I've tried disabling multi-site in wp-config.php file and re-enabling it but it takes me directly to the "Create a Network of WordPress Sites - Enabling the Network" screen.

I need to cancel any pending WordPress multi-site installation and start all over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by deleting every row data in the "wp_site" and "wp_sitemeta" tables in my WordPress database. 
After that, it returned to the "Create a Network of WordPress Sites - Network Details" screen. Please note that I didn't have any active multisite setup.